# Coded UI Test Builder assertions cannot access to DOM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coded-ui-tests

I'm tring to make come UI test using Coded UI. Unfortuanley, It seems to not have access to all DOM elements in browser. 
I want to assert value of one text block in form, and by"Add Assertion" the lowest element i can assert is form itself. All tags contained by form was flatten and putted to "id" property in "Add Assertion" widnows, like in the screen below:

[image]

Is there a way to assert only one tag in form? In this case i want to assert value "Szczegóły przesyłki: 0--1526203258"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your web page is designed. From the image shown it it not clear what field contains the `Szczegóły przesyłki: 0--1526203258`. However, given (1) the scroll bar and (2) that the `Id` field is shown and is empty, it is probably the **Inner Text** field.

Given the number of lines shown above and below the required text you are likely to have selected a larger than necessary part of the screen. When creating an assertion is it often best to move the cross hairs tool around the screen to find the smallest control that contains the required field. Such a UI Control will have no child controls.

I have found that occasionally the Coded UI cross hairs tool loses its place and leaves all four (UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT) arrows grey and inactive, as shown in the screenshot. When this happens try clicking the refresh button located between **Add Assertion** and the arrows. Some of the arrows should then be shown as black and active. If the DOWN arrow is grey (inactive) and some of the other arrows are black then the properties panel shows a UI Control that has no child components. You should be able to find a UI Control that contains only the required text.

Comment: yes, you have right - sometimes arrows just disappear. Thanks for help